# In R & dabestr, how do I get grouped differences correctly?

Tags: r

Using `dabestr` [package](https://github.com/ACCLAB/dabestr) I'm trying to get the differences between two sets of control & test data. Moifying slightly example from help file I tried:

```
library(dabestr)

N <- 70
c1 <- rnorm(N, mean = 50, sd = 20)
t1 <- rnorm(N, mean = 200, sd = 20)
ID <- seq(1:N)
long.data <- tibble::tibble(ID = ID, Control1 = c1, Test1 = t1)

meandiff1 <- long.data %>%
  tidyr::gather(key = Group, value = Measurement, Control1:Test1)

ID <- seq(1:N) + N
c2 <- rnorm(N, mean = 100, sd = 70)
t2 <- rnorm(N, mean = 100, sd = 70)
long.data <- tibble::tibble(ID = ID, Control2 = c2, Test2 = t2)

meandiff2 <- long.data %>%
  tidyr::gather(key = Group, value = Measurement, Control2:Test2)

meandiff <- dplyr::bind_rows(meandiff1, meandiff2)

paired_mean_diff <- 
  dabest(meandiff, x = Group, y = Measurement,
         idx = c("Control1", "Test1", "Control2", "Test2"),
         paired = TRUE,
         id.col = ID)

plot(paired_mean_diff)
```

I get these results:

[image]

So not only is everything compared to `Control1` but also the `paired = TRUE` option seems to have no effect. I was hoping to get something similar to examples from the package page:

[image]

Any pointers on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a paired plot, you want to nest the idx keyword option as such:

```
paired_mean_diff <- 
  dabest(meandiff, x = Group, y = Measurement,
    idx = list(c("Control1", "Test1"), 
               c("Control2", "Test2")),
    paired = TRUE,
    id.col = ID)
```